# При сворачивание приложения на Nougat выдает ошибку Android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, android-fragment

Приложение запускается и работает хорошо и при повороте экрана. Но при сворачивание экрана выдает ошибку. Это происходит на Nougat. В более старых версиях ошибки не происходит при сворачивание экрана.

```
07-12 09:25:04.245 26750-26750/com.example.ewrei.tanksapi E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1585564)
07-12 09:25:04.245 26750-26750/com.example.ewrei.tanksapi D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-12 09:25:04.253 26750-26750/com.example.ewrei.tanksapi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.ewrei.tanksapi, PID: 26750
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1585564 bytes
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3781)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                             Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1585564 bytes
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3636)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3773)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Сам код

```
 public class Fragment_sravnenie_print extends Fragment {
        private Player player;
        private Player playerSravnenie;

    ...................................

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sravnenie_print, container, false);

         Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                player = bundle.getParcelable("player");
                playerSravnenie = bundle.getParcelable("player_sravnenie");
            }
    .................................
            //Получение ресурсов и заполнение RecyclerView
            }

            }
```

Пробовал сделать у себя так же как из документации [Обработка изменений в режиме выполнения](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). Ну ничего не получилось. Ошибка не изменилась. Это ошибка возникает во всех фрагментах где использую `Bundle`. Есть фрагмент где я получаю данные через класс наследованный от `Application`. Там спокойно сворачивается и не выдает никаких ошибок

**Update:
Пробую так**

```
 public class Fragment_sravnenie_print extends Fragment {
        private Player player;
        private Player playerSravnenie;

    ...................................
    private DataFragment dataFragment;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sravnenie_print, container, false);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("data");

    if (dataFragment == null) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            player = bundle.getParcelable("player");
            playerSravnenie = bundle.getParcelable("player_sravnenie");
        }
        // add the fragment
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, "data").commit();
        // load the data from the web
        dataFragment.setPlayer(player);
        dataFragment.setPlayer_sravnenie(playerSravnenie);


    }
    else
    {

        player = dataFragment.getPlayer();
        playerSravnenie = dataFragment.getPlayer_sravnenie();
    }

    .................................
            //Получение ресурсов и заполнение RecyclerView
            }

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // store the data in the fragment
        Log.e("TEST", "Data_Destroy");
        dataFragment.setPlayer(player);
        dataFragment.setPlayer_sravnenie(playerSravnenie);
    }

                }
```

И фрагмент

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment{

private Player player;
private Player player_sravnenie;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public Player getPlayer_sravnenie() {
    return player_sravnenie;
}

public void setPlayer_sravnenie(Player player_sravnenie) {
    this.player_sravnenie = player_sravnenie;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в бандле объекты, размером
[более 1 мегабайта](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

Попробуйте сохранять большие данные в локальную базу данных, или просто в файл, и не забывайте о кэшировании :)

Comment: Как я вас понял, я могу перевести свои данные в json, потом сохранить в файл или локальную базу. После чего в Bundle я передаю имя файла или название таблицы локальной бд. И во фрагменте уже достаю эти данные

Comment: Да, можно так и сделать. Только, если захотите в базу сохранять, переводить в json не нужно. Что выбирать - базу или json - решайте исходя из задачи. Если, к примеру, будете делать по данным различные выборки, или удалять/вставлять новые данные по мере работы, то лучше базу использовать. Если просто загрузили и используете кусок данных с сервера - можно файлом ограничиться

Comment: Спасибо вы мне очень помогли, буду делать)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `setRetainInstance(true);` в  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` фрагмент, а в главном `Activity` добавьте сохранение данных в `Fragment` в методе `onDestroy` вашего активити и их загрузку в `onCreate`.

Сохранение объектов с сохранением состояния во фрагменте во время изменения конфигурации в режиме выполнения:

1. Расширьте класс `Fragment` и объявите ссылки на объекты, сохраняющие
   состояние.
2. Вызовите `setRetainInstance(boolean)`, когда фрагмент создан.
3. Добавьте фрагмент в операцию.
4. Используйте `FragmentManager` для извлечения фрагмента при перезапуске
   операции.

У вас случается ситуация описанная [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Не получилось, и данные сохраняю в фрагменте. Так как данные я получаю от сервера во фрагменте и передаю уже в этот фрагмент. Обновил в вопросе, как делал. Ну ошибка осталась та же